# Configure catalog search function

Tags: search, catalogsearch

Have an issue here and would love to hear an advice. Simple example:
I type snake top in the search bar and it shows me all products that contain top and snake in the title or description. I, however, want it to show me only snake tops, nothing else.

Is there a way to configure that in Magento without an extension? Was looking at Klevu but if there is a way to do it in Magento manually, would rather go for that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Magento default search is limited in capability.

I use a module by Templates Master called Ajax Search - only $29.

Many settings to alter the search "sensitivity" can be set in the back end and I believe this will do what you want.